# How to say when you're doing a specific thing?

Tags: particles

I'm still a little confused on the nuances of the の particle. For example, let's say "I played Dota 2."
Would that be

> "Dota 2**の**ゲームをしました。"

Comment: Are you asking about whether your usage of の is correct, or do you want ot know whether you need to include のゲーム at all?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your tendency to want to use `の` in this case. However when you want to introduce the name of something, you should use `という`. (assuming you are introducing it for the first time). So you could say, `Dota2というゲームをしました。` If the game is mutually understood you can just say `Dota2をしました。`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.
In this case, の binds the two nouns together.

Of course, there are other cases where you use の with a different meaning, but in your case, it seems right.